# Python or Django: handle raised exception from imported library without internal server error

Tags: python, django, exception

I've created a library that connects to some remote JSON api. I have a Django application that will render a internal server error, if my library fails connecting to the resource (504 error). Here is a hypothetical example that kind of shows the layout of my library's code.

### mymodule.py

```
...
class Error(Exception):
    """class placeholder for errors"""
class theObject(object):
    @classmethod
    def get(self, params = {}):
        url = 'http://somewhere.com/collection.json%s' % (urlencode(params))
        try:
            response = unicode(urlopen(url).read(), 'utf8').decode()
            dictionary = json.loads(response)
            result = ApiObject(dictionary)
            return result
        except HTTPError, e:
            raise Error(e.read())
        except (ValueError, KeyError), e:
            raise Error('Invalid Response')

class Person(theObject):
    @classmethod
    def get_person(cls, person_id):
        params = {'id':person_id)
        result = super(Stuff, cls).get(params)
        return result
```

### view.py

```
import mymodule
...
remote_result = module.Person.get_person(person_id=person)
...
```

Is there a recommended way to alert the user that the resource is too busy? This would be better than rendering an internal server error from my current ajax requests.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured my problem out.  I feel stupid, because the solution is so simple.  Hopefully, this will help someone out in the future who runs into the same issue.  If a HTTP connection fails on an imported library, you can avoid rendering a server error page and produce a friendly notification for the client.

All it requires is that you find the class in the imported library that handles the errors.  In this case, it is named "Error."

```
import mymodule
try:
    [do a bunch of things...] 

except mymodule.Error:  
    error = "Remote servers appear to be busy. Please try again."
    return HttpResponse(error)
```

You can and probably should customize it to handle exceptions specific to the raised HTTPError.

Cheers!